# Is it possible that analogWrite(4, 1024) could cause hang of the ESP8266?

Tags: arduino, infinite-loop, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I wonder if calling such a line:

```cpp
analogWrite(4, 1024);
```

could cause ESP8266 to hang?

I'm asking because my ESP8266 hangs after about a week of normal working. This is terrible to debug but I managed to narrow down the problem to a function which uses analogWrite(). I analyzed it and it occurred to me that the values are ranging from 0 to 1024 instead of from 0 to 255, right?

This is `analogWrite()` function from Arduino:

```cpp
extern "C" void analogWrite(uint8_t pin, int value) {
  if (pin >= ESP_PINS_OFFSET) {
    __analogWrite(pin - ESP_PINS_OFFSET, value);
  }
  else {
    wifio::analogWrite(pin, value);
  }
}
```

It calls some SDK's commands which I don't have knowledge about and I'm not sure if it's possible to verify what they're doing?

Comment: You could use a lib that saves the crash info in EEPROM to do a stack trace: https://github.com/krzychb/EspSaveCrash

Comment: Unfortunately, it wouldn't save anything because there is no crash. I have my device connected to serial 24h. If there were a crash, there would be no problem since ESP8266 restarts after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `analogWrite()` with a value outside the allowed range will likely cause undefined behavior; you should definitely correct this before attending to anything else:

> Syntax for the ESP8266: analogWrite(pin, valueParameters pin: the pin
>   to write to. value: the duty cycle: between 0 (always off) and 1023
>   (always on).

Forget other debugging tasks until you get this corrected.

Comment: On the ESP8266, the range is by default 0-1023 as written in the online reference: http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.3.0/doc/reference.html#analog-output

Comment: Good to know, but still 1024 is 1023+1.

Comment: i've found over-value to "roll-over" with no ill side-effects, are you sure about the answer?

Comment: I have not tested it; instead I constrain all values to defined ranges.  But my answer is based on the general principle that it's good practice to adhere to the ranges allowed by the library functions.  Nothing good can come from unsigned value rollover.